# Find the nth number in fibonacci using c

Tags: c

This task is to find fibanocci of n numbers. TASK: 1.To find fibanocci of n numbers. 2.Use variables n,first=0,second=1,next,c. INPUT FORMAT: Use printf statement. Use scanf to get the number n. Use FOR loop. Use IF....ELSE loop statement. OUTPUT FORMAT: Use printf statement to print the output SAMPLE INPUT: 2 SAMPLE OUTPUT: 3(From HackerRank)

I tried solving above but they asked for input 2 output should be 3 But They also asked output 01 on input 1.Can You tell me How to proceed?

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int fib(int n)
{

  int f[n+1];
  int i;

  f[0] = 0;
  f[1] = 1;

  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
  {
     f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
  }

  return f[n];
}

int main ()
{
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("%02d", fib(n));
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is a custom fibbonacci or not?

Comment: because fibbonacci order is like: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...

Comment: Is something wrong with the code you have?

Comment: i don't think so according to my code i am getting 1,1,2,3,.... but i am confused on question, i was wondering if it was wrong as how will you get first term 1 and next term 3

Comment: But the leaderboard shows that the question is solved by many people.

Comment: Note, with `n == 0`, `f[1] = 1;` is a problem as the array is not that large.  Perhaps `if (n < 1)  return 0;` before `int f[n+1];`?

Comment: So i got that the question is not wrong but wrongly put in words. It is asking series in 0112358......... format

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get `01` is you use a `%02d` conversion specifier.

You should use a plain `%d` conversion to get `1` for `1` and `1` etc...

Comment: Whenever i submit the code it asked 01 but i was getting 1.So I needed %02d.Now my problem was they said input for 2 should be 3 in the question.The solution proceeded in 2 steps one being 01 as answer, other one was 01123 as answer which is the series till 5th number not the 5th number in the series.But you can see that question seemed to ask the nth number in the series.That was my whole doubt.

Comment: I'm afraid it is unclear what you are asking, or more precisely, it is unclear what they are asking you.